# Getting error, while using numpy.concatenate

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-multilearn

So basically I am having two numpy arrays `x_chunk` and `y_chunk` of dimensions `[10,512,512,50]` each. I converted them, to dimensions `[10,13107200]` using the code:

```
x_chunk=x_chunk.reshape(10,13107200)
y_chunk=y_chunk.reshape(10,13107200)
```

Now I am using `skmultiflow KNN Classifier`, and trying to fit these data using `partial_fit`

```
model.partial_fit(x_chunk, y_chunk)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-d3e5ffef750e> in <module>()
     53     x_chunk=x_chunk.reshape(10,13107200)
     54     y_chunk=y_chunk.reshape(10,13107200)
---> 55     model.partial_fit(x_chunk, y_chunk)
     56     n_loop += 1
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skmultiflow/lazy/knn.py in partial_fit(self, X, y, classes, weight)
    178 
    179         for i in range(r):
--> 180             self.window.add_element(np.asarray([X[i]]), np.asarray([[y[i]]]))
    181         return self
    182 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skmultiflow/utils/data_structures.py in add_element(self, X, y)
    968             raise TypeError("None type not supported as the buffer, call configure() to set up the InstanceWindow")
    969 
--> 970         aux = np.concatenate((X, y), axis=1)
    971         self._buffer = np.concatenate((self._buffer, aux), axis=0)
    972         self._n_samples += 1

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

It says that the dimension of the arrays should be same, however both arrays are of same dimensions, so what is the problem?

**edit**

Model which I used is:

```
from skmultiflow.lazy import KNN
model = KNN(n_neighbors=8, max_window_size=2000, leaf_size=40)
```

Comment: It's not working with your two input arrays directly.  What I'd do is look at the code for `partial_fit` and trace the flow of the inputs.  The traceback tells us where to look, but doesn't provide enough details by itself.  But first, I'd review the docs for `partial_fit` to make sure the inputs fit what it expects (but also check `model` if you provided inputs to that as well).

Comment: @hpaulj see the edit.